# Problematic modulo operator in a preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, loops, modulo

It's late, and I can't figure out the pattern to the below problem ( which has been simplified  ). The problem is with the process function.

```
<?php
function imcrement_image_id( $template ){
  return preg_replace_callback('/%image_id%/', 'process', $template );
}

function process( $match ){
    static $count = 0;
    $count++;
    $output = '';
    if( $count %2 == 0){
        $output =  'image-' . (--$count);
        $count++;
    } else {
    $output =  'image-' . $count;
    }
return $output;
}  
?>
```

The application of the functions is seen in this snippet. I am trying to replace the image_id **twice** per loop, so that `figure id="%image_id"` and `<a href="%image_id"` match.

```
<?php for ($i=0; $i <3 ; $i++): ?>
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<figure id="%image_id%">

          <a href="#%image_id%" >
              <img src="http://placehold.it/550x209">
              <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
          </a>
          <p class="description">Quisque facilisis </p>  
</figure>
<?php $template .= ob_get_clean(); ?>
<?php endfor; ?>
// later...
echo $template;
```

Currently this code does work, but it produces markup like this:

```
 <figure id="image-1">
 <a href="#image-1">
 ...
 <figure id="image-3">
 <a href="#image-3">
 ...
 <figure id="image-3">
 <a href="#image-3">
```

I'd like it to be `image-1 image-1, image-2 image-2, image-3 image-3` and so on. Pointers always appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: the `%` sign here is not a modulo operator; it's just a character in a string. The string `%image_id%` is being used as a placeholder for string replacement. It could have been any string; it just happens to contain percent signs. No modulo involved at all.

Comment: @SDC you overlooked this line: `if( $count %2 == 0)`

Comment: @feb - meh, you'r right. I guess I was thrown by the question title talking about modulo in preg_replace_callback, combined with the placeholder in the preg_replace_callback and the placeholder string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
function process( $match ){
    static $count = 1;
    $count++;
    return 'image-' . floor($count/2);
}
```

The logic:

- `$count` will be 2,3,4,5,6... at the `return` statement
- `$count/2` will return 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3...
- `floor($count/2)` will return 1, 1, 2, 2, 3...